# MongoDB Count Distinct Speed

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm using the following code in PyMongo:

```
db.collection.group(["myField"], {}, {"count":0},"function(o, p){p.count++}" )
```

Which correctly returns the numbers I need but the search takes 30 seconds to complete. Would indexing speed this up? I find it hard to know whether fields should or shouldn't be indexed because I read an article which said don't index too much or everything will slow down so I've indexed nothing..

Comment: what are you trying to count?

Comment: Types of address, there are 5 possible values

Comment: sum:1 would count

Comment: Have you tried `collection.count` with a query filter. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/

Comment: Could you show how to use in the code please? I'm not sure where the sum:1 would go in this context.

Comment: @ Kofrasa - this returns a count of the query if I were to use find.  I need to return the unique values together with the count of these unique values.  My function works, it's just slow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"group" is slow because it has to execute a Javascript function for each document it encounters. [For this reason, the MongoDB manual says "group" is deprecated.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.group/#db.collection.group) "aggregate" has replaced "group" as a fast modern way to do tasks like this:

```
for result in c.aggregate([{
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$myField",
        "count": {"$sum": 1}
    }
}]):
    print("%s: %d" % (result["_id"], result["count"]))
```

[See the MongoDB manual section about aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/).

Comment: Amazing!  Thank you so much! Literally don't think I could have got there without this but make total sense now.  Thanks Jesse

Comment: If $myField is an array of objects, can I $map this so I'm counting the individual elements in the array?

Comment: Go ahead and ask a new question if you want help with counting elements of an array of objects. Answering followup questions here in the comments is awkward.

Answer (score 0):

### Count existing keys

See: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/

`db.collection.count({"myField": {"$exists": True} })`

### Count by grouping key

See: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum

`db.collection.aggregate([{"$group": {"_id": "myField", "count": {"$sum":1} }])`